# Indentation of conditions in if() using Eclipse Code Formatter for Java

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, code-formatting

I would like to set code style in Eclipse Formatter that will align (indent) conditions in `if` instruction to the same column (in case of conditions in different lines).

This is the example of what I would like to achieve:

```
if (very_awesome_variable == quite_awesome_value_1 ||
    very_awesome_variable == quite_awesome_value_2 ||
    very_awesome_variable == quite_awesome_value_3) {
    // do something
} else if (very_awesome_variable == quite_awesome_value_4 ||
           very_awesome_variable == quite_awesome_value_5 ||
           very_awesome_variable == quite_awesome_value_6) {
    // do some other thing
}
```

This is what I have currently:

```
if (very_awesome_variable == quite_awesome_value_1 ||
    very_awesome_variable == quite_awesome_value_2 ||
    very_awesome_variable == quite_awesome_value_3) {
    // do something
} else if (very_awesome_variable == quite_awesome_value_4 ||
    very_awesome_variable == quite_awesome_value_5 ||
    very_awesome_variable == quite_awesome_value_6) {
    // do some other thing
}
```

I honestly don't see any option for configuring indentation of such thing.

I also believe that conditions in first block are indented in my way only because I use 4 spaces indentation and `if (` is exactly 4 characters long. It looks like general indentation configuration is applied here.

I would be happy even if I could turn off indentation for such lines and do it manually, so auto formatter will not break this again.

Answer (score 0):

Go into window - preferences java -> code style -> formatter

You can then edit the indentation, simply use the search box to find "if" options

Comment: I am aware of these options. I tried to find correct one, but was unable to, that's why I submitted this quiestion.